# Issues with wifi after installing kubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, kubuntu, iwlwifi

When I was on ubuntu 12.04, everything worked perfectly. I'm now on Kubuntu 15.04. When my session starts, wifi is connected  for less than a minute, and afterwards it disconnects with no way to reconnect.

I always tried to disable the 11n option, as also killing "wpa_supplicant", but it changes nothing.

This is the output of `lspci` command :

```
03:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g [1814:0302]
```

And `iwconfig` :

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

And some system logs after trying to reconnect :

```
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'FreeWifi'
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
25/09/2015 20:38:07 chris-System-Product-Name   NetworkManager[659] <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
```

Any clue on this ?